# Retrieve model fields related which are related to another model (even with intermediate models/foreign_keys)?

Tags: django, django-models, breadth-first-search

I have model A, B and C.

Model C has field X, which is a foreign key to field X_1 in model B.

Model B has field Y, which is a foreign key to field Y_1 in model A.

In a form, I want to retrieve only the related fields from model C, which relate to model A (in whatever way).

Basically, in a form I select the function is on model C, but I select the parent is Model A (this has to do with identifying the sequence of presenting the fields).

What I want to, is from model C, which field(s) relate to model A, and in which way?

In this case, I would post the parent is A, the child is C, and would expect the function to return X_1__Y_1. Where X_1 represents the object in model B, and Y_1 represents the related(/parent) object in model A.

*What I can think of, is a seperate model, to capture **all** relations to other models (through a cron/celery and invoke on first setup, or through manage.py after a migration), through a breadt-first-search or something.
Than I guess I could do with 4 fields: Model, Field, Destination_Model, Relation.*

But it might just be more easy and straightforward than I describe above?

I have model A, B and C.

Model C has field X, which is a foreign key to field X_1 in model B.

Model B has field Y, which is a foreign key to field Y_1 in model A.

In a form, I want to retrieve only the related fields from model C, which relate to model A (in whatever way).

Basically, in a form I select the function is on model C, but I select the parent is Model A (this has to do with identifying the sequence of presenting the fields).

What I want to, is from model C, which field(s) relate to model A, and in which way?

In this case, I would post the parent is A, the child is C, and would expect the function to return X_1__Y_1. Where X_1 represents the object in model B, and Y_1 represents the related(/parent) object in model A.

*What I can think of, is a seperate model, to capture **all** relations to other models (through a cron/celery and invoke on first setup, or through manage.py after a migration), through a breadt-first-search or something.
Than I guess I could do with 4 fields: Model, Field, Destination_Model, Relation.*

But it might just be more easy and straightforward than I describe above?